# auto resizing textarea in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a ASP.NET Webpage using Bootstrap and jQuery.

I have recently implemented a modal to show a log. The modal is shown when clicking a link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logData">Open</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="logData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logDataLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Log for @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Alias)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="form-control log" rows="5" placeholder="Log is empty.">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Log)</textarea>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal contains a textarea that doesn't autoresize.

I have found the following code:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
}).on('input', function () {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
```

which should enable my textareas to autoresize and it works other places in my code, but not in this modal above. At least not when typing in the textarea, but upon opening the modal it does seem to autoresize.

Does anyone have an idea of why? And eventually on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the html for the modal exist when the page is first rendered,  or isit being loaded dynamically using ajax (in which case you need event delegation)?

Comment: It is a part of a partialView that is being drawn when table row is being clicked. Actually the piece of code you helped me with yesterday. So I guess I need some sort of event delegation?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I read this https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ but I can't really seem to figure out how to achieve event delegation with my code

Comment: `$(document).on('input', 'textarea', function() { ... }` but for best performance, replace `document` with the closest ancestor of the textarea which exists when the page is first rendered

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. 

How would I do if the direct parent of the textarea is a `<p>`? Would I just do `$('p').on('input', 'textarea', function()...`? Can't I use the textarea itself? E.g. `$('textarea').on('input', 'textarea', function()...`?

Comment: And can I use `ìd`s and `class` as well? E.g. `$('#something')` or `$('.something')`?

Comment: You cannot use the 2nd snippet because the events are attached when the page is first rendered, and at that point the textarea does not exist yet. For the first snippet, if the `<p>` element exists when the page is first rendered, then its best to give it an `id` attribute so you can use `<p id="xx">` and `$('#xx').on('input', 'textarea', function() { ... }` - it just means that only that `<p>` element will be listening for any `input`  events for any `<textarea>` elements within it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127376/discussion-between-zeliax-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code which will work if the textarea is not hidden (e.g in a modal that is not shown yet)

```
let setHeight = (input) => {

    input.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    input.style.height = 0;

    input.style.height = `${ input.scrollHeight + 2 }px`;

};

$('textarea').on('input, keyup', function () {
    setHeight(this);
})
```

for bootstrap modal, u can do something like this:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('textarea').each(function () {
        setHeight(this);
    });
})
```